# Changing view background image in loop

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have 3 images for setting self.view.background . What i' am trying  , setting background like Twitter iOS APP Login UI ( Changing background image randomly in every 5 second. )

All random process has done , what i really in trouble is , when i am using UIAnimation it randomise  it sync mode. When it works, whole UI waits UIAnimation process as expected .

here is my code : ( I am calling this method at the end of the viewDidLoad method :

Note: also , setting alpha is not working ..

```
-(void)startBackgroundImageChange
{

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                          delay:0.2
                        options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                     animations:^{

                         [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

                         self.view.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[self setBackgroundImage]]];

                         self.view.alpha = 1.0;

                         //here you may add any othe actions, but notice, that ALL of them will do in SINGLE step. so, we setting ONLY xx coordinate to move it horizantly first.
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){

                         //here any actions, thet must be done AFTER 1st animation is finished. If you whant to loop animations, call your function here.
                         self.view.alpha = 0.3;
                         [self startBackgroundImageChange];
                     }];

        });

}
```

Any help will be appreciated ..

Comment: Your code is taking 5 seconds to fade in the image. What you want is to run the code every 5 seconds but the animation should only last a short time.

Comment: I want , change self.view.background image every 5 seconds randomly with fade-in , fade-out  animation. [UIImage imageNamed:[self setBackgroundImage]] returns image name as NSString after random operation.

Comment: Use a timer to fire every 5 seconds, and change the image. Ideally create the timer in viewWillAppear, and remove it on viewWillDisappear.

Comment: I am going to try with NSTimer ,i think it can be handle with timer ...

Comment: you can try my updated code ..

Comment: I tried, It works fine but UI unreachable when background image changes.. It's really weird that async process does not work ?

Comment: I think after completion:^(BOOL finished){ , calling method makes async process un-useable ...